# ArcMap python field calculator function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a field that has three entries as strings: "278957", "278961", and "12345678". When I use if/elif/else I can correctly replace the first two conditions in my code below but the problem is that for all entries that do not meet the conditions the values are replaced with . I thought writing "else: dsm == dsm" would preserve the original values if no conditions were met but it instead it overwrites the values to . Where am I going wrong?

> `def ifDSM(dsm):
>     if dsm == "278957":
>       return "10002343"
>     elif dsm == "278961":
>       return "10000550"
>     else:
>       dsm == dsm`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dsm == dsm is a relational operator that will always be true but returns nothing.

Change your code to:

```
else:
    return dsm
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on the last line you're doing a comparison operator rather than an assignment, perhaps this is messing up your "else" somehow.

Instead of assigning the value to itself, however, I might use a python [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420705/example-use-of-continue-statement-in-python)